# Google App Engine - BadArgumentError - don't understand why

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

I'm getting a BadArgumentError in my GAE app, and I can't figure out why.

I've got a Entity model that I essentially use as a join table between different entities.  I've got some legacy code that iterates through all the instances of this Entity to check (and fill) any known holes.  I've slowly been getting rid of it as I verify I've got other error-checking procedures in place, but can't figure this bug out.  (If you think through the logic it essentially does absolutely nothing at this point, and if it wasn't for this error I would delete it all.)

The code to check/fill known holes (missing ReferenceProperties) is set up as a Task Queue.  The main handler sends the key().id() as a parameter to the worker, which then looks up the instance, checks to see if it's got that ReferenceProperty, and deletes it if it doesn't.

What's weird is that the logging shows that there *is* an Entity instance, but when I try to delete it I get a BadArgumentError.  Also, when I look it up on the App Engine Datastore Viewer

```
(SELECT * FROM InvestorRoundPair where __key__ = KEY('InvestorRoundPair', 5701213970497536))
```

it doesn't return any results.

So it looks like there's no Entity instance that actually exists... but somehow the handler still is able to find it and send it to the worker?

For as much as I've done in App Engine, I'm still very much an amateur and may well be missing something incredibly obvious.  But maybe not?  I'd really love some help in understanding what's going on and what (if anything) I should do to fix it.

models.py

```
class InvestorRoundPair(db.Model):
    investor = db.ReferenceProperty(SeedInvestor, collection_name = 'investorgroup')
    funding_round = db.ReferenceProperty(FundingRound, collection_name = 'fundingroundgroup')
    accelerator_entry = db.ReferenceProperty(SeedAccelerator, collection_name = 'acceleratorgroup')
    company_entry = db.ReferenceProperty(SeedCompany, collection_name = 'companygroup')
```

Classes/Methods

```
class FillHolesHandler(handlers.BaseRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        listofholes = InvestorRoundPair.all().order('-funding_round')
        for entry in listofholes:
            objid = entry.key().id()
            taskqueue.add(url='/investorgraph/graphholefiller', params={'objid': objid}, queue_name='holefiller')

class GraphHoleFillerWorker(handlers.BaseRequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        objid = self.request.get('objid')
        entry = InvestorRoundPair.get_by_id(int(objid))
        logging.info('InvestorRoundPair %s', objid)
        try:
            fundingroundkey = entry.funding_round.key().id()
        except AttributeError:
            db.delete(entry)
```

Error

```
InvestorRoundPair 5701213970497536
[...]
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~seed-db/1.383964211518800837/investorgraph.py", line 132, in post
    db.delete(entry)
[...]
BadArgumentError: Expected one of (<type 'basestring'>, <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity'>, <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Key'>); received None (a NoneType).
```

Comment: do you have the log what entry variable is holding?

Comment: `entry = InvestorRoundPair.get_by_id(int(objid))` -- entry here is None, so you're trying to delete something which does not exists.

Comment: But the FillHolesHandler sends each instance of InvestorRoundPair to the worker... doesn't it have to exist in order to send it to the worker to process?  That's why I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that your code is not idempotent. App Engine does not guarantee that any particular task will only be executed once. It is therefore possible for your task to run, delete the entity, then run again and fail to find it.

You should simply check that the `get_by_id` works and `entry` is not None before attempting to access its attributes or delete it.